# A hollow spherical body rolls without slipping on applying force 2/3R above the com. What happens if I apply below?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, rotation

[image: Two cases]
d=2/3R

The surface is rough.
Both have same radii.

I read about the first case. However, what happens if I apply the force 2/3R below the com?

I'm unable to make a proper diagram and explain it to myself.

Does friction play a part in both cases? Is there any difference in both cases?